# How can I make my express route more dynamic

Tags: node.js, express

I want to make my express route have the ability be able to pass anything past the first set of parameters to it

```
app.get('/views/app/:name/*', appRoutes.partials);
```

and in my route file I have

```
exports.partials = function(req, res) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    var partial = req.params.partial;
    var content = "";
    res.render('views/app/'+name+'/'+partial,content);
};
```

I know partial would not be the variable to use there but how can I make whatever passes through the star append to the end?

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The star (`*`) placeholder will capture all the remaining text and place it under key '0' on params object (if you had more `*`'s, they would go to '1', '2'...).

So, how about this:

```
exports.partials = function(req, res) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    var partial = req.params['0'];
    var content = "";
    res.render('views/app/'+name+'/'+partial,content);
};
```

If you expect the wildcard part to be an arbitrary route, you will have to parse it yourself. For example:

```
// url: /views/app/profile/main/dashboard
exports.partials = function(req, res) {
    var path = req.params['0'].split('/');
    console.log(path[0], path[1]); //>> main dashboard
};
```

Comment: so if for instance I did views/app/profile/main/dashboard :

name = profile,
req.params['0'] = 'main',
req.params['1'] = dashboard

?

Comment: Updated answer anyway. :-)